# PowerBI - Filtered Table in a Cell of another Table

Tags: powerbi

I have the following problem:

Let's say I have to generate a PowerBI Dashboard based on two Tables:

Table Population:

```
Year,    ZIP,  Population
2017,   1010,       15324
2017,   2020,        1576
2017,   3030,       21565
2018,   1010,       15585
2018,   2020,        1621
2018,   3030,       21605
```

Table Doctors:

```
Year,        Name,     ZIP,        Long,          Lat
2017,    Doc Adam,    1010,   48.434209,    14.332321
2017,   Doc Karol,    1010,   48.234211,    14.358444
2017,    Doc Mike,    1010,   48.658345,    14.257785
2017,     Doc Tom,    2020,   48.245672,    14.746433
2017,   Doc Peter,    3030,   48.937432,    14.357843
2017,     Doc Sam,    3030,   48.246345,    14.343545
2018,    Doc Adam,    1010,   48.434209,    14.332321
2018,   Doc Karol,    2020,   48.456654,    14.345545
2018,    Doc Mike,    1010,   48.658345,    14.257785
2018,     Doc Tom,    2020,   48.245672,    14.746433
2018,     Doc Sam,    3030,   48.246345,    14.343545
```

Summarized, this data represents the development of the population in certain areas, and a list of doctors, who are practicing in these areas.

My job is now, to create a PowerBI dashboard with two ArcGIS maps, where on one map the population is displayed via a colored area map, and on the other map, each doctor is represented by a bubble.

So far so easy, but my problem is that both maps should be linked -> if you select one area on the population map, the other map should zoom to the same area and filter for all doctors within the selected ZIP

Therefore I have to combine these two tables in one single table, which can be shared by the two maps.

But how can I do this in PowerBI? The resulting table should look something like this:

```
Year,    ZIP,  Population,    Docs
                              DocName,         Long,          Lat
 2017,   1010,       15324    Doc Adam,   48.434209,    14.332321
                              Doc Karol,  48.234211,    14.358444
                              Doc Mike,   48.658345,    14.257785
 2017,   2020,        1576    Doc Tom,    48.245672,    14.746433
 2017,   3030,       21565    Doc Peter,  48.937432,    14.357843
                              Doc Sam,    48.246345,    14.343545
 2018,   1010,       15585    Doc Adam,   48.434209,    14.332321
                              Doc Mike,   48.658345,    14.257785
 2018,   2020,        1621    Doc Karol,  48.456654,    14.345545
                              Doc Tom,    48.245672,    14.746433
 2018,   3030,       21605    Doc Sam,    48.246345,    14.343545
```

THX in advance & BR
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine the tables, as the data is at different granularity. Instead, build a data model that lets you filter the zip codes (and maybe years as well?) on a central dimension, that will then filter both the "fact" tables.

In essence:

1. Add a table that holds all the unique zip codes. You can do this using DAX: `Zipcodes=UNION(VALUES('Population'[Zip]), VALUES('Doctors'[Zip]))`
2. Hide the ZIP column on both the Population and Doctors tables.
3. Create two relationships, one from the ZIP-column on the Population table, the other from the ZIP-column on the Doctors table, and point them to the Zip-column on the Zipcodes table.

Now, change your visuals to use the Zip-column on the new Zipcodes table. You should then see, that selecting a zipcode will affect both tables.

You can do the same thing for the Year column, if you like.

Comment: I've tried it over the weekend, and unfortunately, the two ArcGIS maps do not respond to each other.

Comment: That's weird. ArcGIS maps should support interactions. Are you sure you're actually filtering on the shared Zip-codes dimension? What happens if you create a new report page and add two Bar Chart visuals: One containing population by Zip Code, another containing the number of doctors per Zip Code. Do they interact the way you expect?